# If I override a template in core Magento 2, could it be removed when upgrading to future versions of Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, theme

For my personal shoping website I am trying to override some of the XML and PHTML files of default luma theme.  I am just eding the vendor/theme-frontend-luma folder directly.

Just want to know when I do the Magento upgrade in the future will my custom changes will be wiped off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few different methods to override a template in Magento 2. The three main options are

- Path (theme)
- Layout (theme, module)
- Plugin (module)

### Path

If you are overriding a template for a theme, you only have to place the theme in the corresponding path of the module directory within that theme. So for example, If you want to override `Magento/Wishlist/view/frontend/templates/view.phtml` you can simply add your own view.php file in `{theme_dir}/Magento_Wishlist/view/frontend/templates/view.phtml` and that template will be used without the need to change any xml files. In this situation, the only way your template override would be wiped is if an update or another module changed the template attribute for the block that defines it or if another module or extension went the plugin route.

### Layout

For this option you only need to override the block's template attribute. Doing it this way means your changes will be wiped if another module tries to do the same thing to the same block and their xml is merged in after yours, if magento changes the name of the block, or if the layout file get's renamed.

### Plugin

A plugin would override the template that get's passed to the block class's toHtml method. This is probably the least conventional method and hardest to debug but it would do the job. Your template could be overridden if the class attribute on the block that defines that template was changed or potentially if another module also tried to override that template the same way.

In summary... yes, it's possible. It is not very likely for an update from Magento to break your override of a template. Your bigger concern should be other third party modules.

Comment: i make new folder in app/design with files copy from vendor . After reload default home magento 2 luma not change anything. I don't want change file directly from vendor