# How do the changes to the frontend in magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, php, frontend

How do the changes to the frontend
For example, I want to make a new or Heder or Checkout or Search or Catalog...

What are the files and paths to allow me to amend the files?

Answer (score 5):

- If you want to make a new Header or Checkout or Search or Catalog you
  can create your custom module in **app/code** and override the
  existing template of the specific which you want to override.
- you need to create layout file in your custom module and load your
  custom template which you want to override.

Another way is **creating the new theme**

- create a new theme inside **app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{yourTheme}/**.
  You can use Blank or Luma theme
- You can also create new theme which inherites from Blank (inheritance
  is defined within theme.xml). If you are already using some theme
  then skip this step.
- Override the layout file and template file which you want to change
- If you have any css changes then Use grunt to compile your .less into deployment files

For more reference how to create theme refer this link - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Run below **commands** after creation of theme.

```
- php bin/magento cache:clean
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create new theme, refer this docs for [How to create new theme?](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)

**Apply new created theme from backend** given path below

```
Content -> Design -> Configuration
```

And then you have to configure compilation of style in admin path given below

```
Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Front-end development workflow
```

change to

```
Client side less compilation
```

run below command to set developer mode

```
- php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Then edit your theme styles module wise and other `web/css/source` (common style)

```
app/design/frontend/<vendor_name>/<theme_name>
```

and clear cache and deploy static-content

```
- php bin/magento cache:clean
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the your own theme on the top of lumia/blank..

more you can find here..

[If I override a template in core Magento 2, could it be removed when upgrading to future versions of Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97125/if-i-override-a-template-in-core-magento-2-could-it-be-removed-when-upgrading-t)

Answer (score 0):

Copy core magento file from

```
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates
```

create your theme and paste all file to:

```
app/design/frontend/MyModule/MyTheme/Magento_Theme/
```